# Unit testing Google wave robots in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-wave

Any tips or best practices for unit testing Google Wave robots written in Java? I'm expecting to deploy on AppEngine, if that helps. I'm a fan of TDD but new to both Wave Robots and AppEngine, so I'm hoping to use TDD to help me explore the design space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of reading and tinkering, I've come up with a solution combining AppEngine, JUnit, and Wave. I describe all the details in my blog post: http://paulgestwicki.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/unit-testing-google-wave-robots/